# Failed to get blob content present in my Azure storage container using Postman

Tags: azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I am trying to get blob content present in my Azure storage container using Postman.

I created a Service Principal in Azure Ad and got access token successfully using scope as `https://storage.azure.com/.default`

I am trying to call query in Postman like below:

```
GET
https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/filename
```

When I am calling the above query to get the blob, I got the below error:

```
<?xml  version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:d60dec8d-401e-0084-0ccd-8be567000000
Time:2022-06-27T15:33:38.4195186Z</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Authentication scheme Bearer is not supported in this version.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

What does the above error mean? Please help me to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error usually occurs if you missed adding **`x-ms-version`** header while calling the query.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

**To resolve the error, I added **`x-ms-version`** header like below and got the blob content successfully:**

[image]